# System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.'

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Market
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Calculadora_Panel.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
            InitializeComponent();

}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Market
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Calculadora_Panel.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
            InitializeComponent();

        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Calculadora = new Form2();
        Calculadora.Show();
        Calculadora_Panel.Visible = true;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        panel4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 PLista = new Form3();
        PLista.Show();
        Calculadora_Panel.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = true;
        panel4.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculadora_Panel.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        panel4.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void otherForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
    }

    private void About_buttom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AboutBox1 About = new AboutBox1();
        About.Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Antes de tudo, vc poderia ter acrescentado seu código a sua pergunta usando a função Editar. Não procurei me atentar a botões e design em forma geral e sim ao problema.

Pelo que puder perceber seu erro provavelmente deve ser esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode evitar isso usando as propriedades dos controles depois do método `InitializeComponents()`, pois nele é onde os componentes do Formulário são instaciados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra alternativa é fazer as modificações no `EventLoad`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber o que acontece no método `InitializeComponent()`, você pode dar dois click no arquivo `FormN.Designer.cs`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

As variáveis panel3 e panel4 deveriam referenciar instâncias do objeto Calculador_Panel, referenciar elementos pertencentes à Calculadora_Panel ou de qual outra classe? Você não declarou a inicialização dos objetos em nenhuma parte do código postado, portanto você não pode atribuir valor à atributos das mesmas. Se você estiver tentando modificar um atributo estático, então não deveria fazer isso através de uma instância do objeto

```
panel3 = new Calculadora_Panel(atributos);
panel4 = new Calculadora_Panel(atributos);
```

Se esse não for o problema, você precisa detalhar melhor o seu problema e postar o restante do seu código para que possamos resolver o problema.

Comment: Sou muito iniciante, quando o programa abrir quero que o panel3 e 4 fiquem invisivel, quando clicar no botão o panel4 e o painel da calculadora fique invisivel